# Get list overflow to happen on x axis / horizontally

Tags: css

I have a list with 3 elements that are a certain size that fit in a container (the `<fieldset>` that can only hold one list item.

Right now, the other list items are overflowing underneath, I need the to overflow to the right on the x axis.

Here is a picture of what I am talking about:

[image]

And here is the page where this is happening: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/270523/help/setup.html

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Please share your code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, that is a fairly odd way to use the fieldset element. In my opinion a div (or perhaps a section) element would make much more sense semantically.

Secondly, to achieve the effect I think you're looking for, you'll need to assign a width to the element that contains your three slides (by default the width is set to auto, meaning the element's children will break down to the next line assuming they're block elements). Assign a width of 1200px to the element ul#slides.

Next, set the overflow property to auto on your wrapping element, in your case the fieldset element. This should hopefully get you started on the right track.